# ConsoleAppender instanciation not working: has a private access

Tags: java, log4j

My instanciation of the class ConsoleAppender is not working.

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender;

public class Application {
        private static ConsoleAppender consoleAppender = new ConsoleAppender();
        public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

The info popup error message:

```
'ConsoleAppender(java.lang.String, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Layout<? extends java.io.Serializable>, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager, boolean, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender.Target, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property[])' has private access in 'org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender'
```

Comment: Which version of log4j do you use?

Comment: @tomeszmh Version 2.14.0. That explains why I don't have a public constructor anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LOG4J `ConsoleAppender` has a private constructor.

```
private ConsoleAppender(
    final String name,
    final Layout<? extends Serializable> layout,
    final Filter filter,
    final OutputStreamManager manager,
    final boolean ignoreExceptions, final Target target,
    final Property[] properties
) { ... }
```

Thus, you need to build it using its own *builder*, e.g.

```
ConsoleAppender.newBuilder()
    .setLayout(...)
    .setName("Example")
    .build()
```

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of log4j had a public constructor. Now he is gone. Use static methods or a builder instead.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.3/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/ConsoleAppender.html